# Detect Socket is closed after remote application is closed forcibly

Tags: java, sockets

I'm having some trouble with Java Sockets.
I have a pair of applications that establish a connection between them (one opens a `ServerSocket`, calls `accept()` and waits, and the other connects via the `Socket(InetAddress,int)` constructor.

After the socket connection is established, a `Thread` is created with this `Runnable`.

```
 public void run() {    
    System.out.print("Watching Socket for closing ");
    while(running) {
        if(socket.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("Socket has been closed");
            break;
        }
    }
    this.running = false;
    //safely ends this application by closing i/o and exiting.
}
```

My problem is that when one of the applications is closed unexpectedly (in my case terminated from Eclipse) calling `Socket.isClosed()` still shows the socket is open, and so the loop keeps running as if the Socket was open.

How can I detect when the Socket is closed when the Java application on the other side is forcibly ended?

Comment: Do you get an IOException while reading?

Comment: No, I haven't added anything that reads and writes yet.

Answer (score 5):

The only way that `socket.isClosed()` return true is if you call yourself `socket.close()` as it is the only part where the boolean will be set to `true`.

What you could do is simply try to read from the `socket` using an `inputStream` and -1 will be returned if it is closed (if the end of stream has been reached).

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) for more information.

Comment: @LukeMoll any feedback on this ?

Comment: sorry, I've been away from my computer. Would reading from the `InputStream` when the connection is closed instantly return -1, but when there is a connection but no data yet it would block until there is? Also would an `IOException` be thrown? I haven't had a chance to read the JavaDoc so I apologise if this is all in there.

Comment: @LukeMoll Yes it would instantly return -1. Yes it would block untill the next byte.No, no exception thrown.  Honestly, this is how it has to be done. If you have problem with blocking then you have to consider multi-threading.

Comment: I'm using InputStream.read() in a loop, but when I close one application the other exits with `SocketException: Connection reset`. It doesn't return -1 before the exception is thrown