# Check if client socket is closed on the server

Tags: java, sockets

How to check, in the server side, if a socket was closed in the client side?

I have this server, which awaits a connection then return 10 messages to the client:

```
public class SocketServidor {
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5963);
        while(true) {
            final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        int valor = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                        out.println("Você acabou de ganhar R$ "+new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00").format(valor)+"!");
                        out.flush();
                        Thread.sleep(valor*1000);
                    }
                    socket.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SocketServidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

And the client, which only reads the values, but stops at the fifth read:

```
public class SocketCliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5963);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String leitura;
        int lidas = 0;
        while((leitura = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lidas++;
            System.out.println(leitura);
            if(lidas == 5){
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is, the server keeps sending the messages to the client even after the fifth read, when the client closes the socket. How to close the socket on the server side when the client closes it on it's side?

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484032/detect-socket-is-closed-after-remote-application-is-closed-forcibly/28484091#28484091

Comment: I cannot see a reason to have the loop on the server side. Why not to move this loop to the client and make the client ask the server for data periodically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Exception is suppressed by PrintWriter.flush()**
You see no exception because the exception is suppressed by PrintWriter.flush(). To check the error state after `PrintWriter.println()`, you can use  `PrintWriter.checkError()` instead of `flush()`. Alternatively, you can use an `OutputStreamWriter` instead of `PrintWriter`, then the exeception won't be suppressed.

1. With checkError

   ```
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5963);
   while(true) {
       final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
       new Thread(() -> {
           try {
               PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
               for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                   int valor = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                   out.println("Você acabou de ganhar R$ "+new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00").format(valor)+"!");
                   //out.flush();
                   if(out.checkError()){
                       System.out.println("Error. Break");
                       break;
                   }
                   Thread.sleep(valor*1000);
               }
               socket.close();
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }).start();
   }
   ```
2. With OutputStreamWriter

   ```
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5963);
   while(true) {
       final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
       new Thread(() -> {
           try {
               Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
               for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                   int valor = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                   out.write("Você acabou de ganhar R$ "+new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00").format(valor)+"!");
                   out.write("\r\n");
                   out.flush();
                   Thread.sleep(valor*1000);
               }
               socket.close();
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }).start();
   }
   ```