# How to close a client Server based program in java without server error

Tags: java

I have a application that is client server based and have used java nio to achieve which is working fine but when a client disconnect abruptly while has request has been sent and the server is processing this is the error that I am getting.

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you not just gracefully handle that exception in your server code?

Comment: If you are shutting down a client, have that client send a "disconnect" message to let the server know it had disconnected, allowing the server to close that client down. If you are closing the server, have the server send a message to every client connected to it. The only way to *instantly* find out if the connection has closed or not is to manually specify it, or to handle the exceptions thrown

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484032/detect-socket-is-closed-after-remote-application-is-closed-forcibly